# Is asking about 2.4 GHz WiFi congestion on-topic on Super User?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

The question [Is 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi band shared across routers?](https://superuser.com/questions/1760220/is-2-4-ghz-wi-fi-band-shared-across-routers) was asked on 2022-12-30 and generated some discussion in the comments about if it's on topic, reproduced here:

> How is this a Question for superuser, as opposed to basic networking pages, please? –
> Robbie Goodwin
>
> @RobbieGoodwin - because there is no "basic networking" SE. There's Network Engineering from where is would be unceremoniously expunged in minutes. – Tetsujin
>
> @RobbieGoodwin unless it’s off topic here (which it isn’t afaik) it doesn’t matter where else it could have been posted. – Tim
>
> @Tim Like it or not, it's up to you to explain how anything about 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi band shared across routers belongs in SE superuser. How could networking be on topic in SE superuser? How could 'this is the closest I could get' be a justification? If there's truly no better SE category why not start your own, rather than troubling SE superuser with something clearly off topic? I suggest SE Network Engineering is a better fit… perhaps not good, but clearly better. Either way, why Ask that here, rather than of your kit manufacturer? – Robbie Goodwin
>
> @RobbieGoodwin Sure, it's on topic: superuser.com/help/on-topic "What topics can I ask about here? ... personal and home computer networking". B) I never used that justification C) One cannot start new Stack Exchanges anymore and D) it's clearly on topic not off E) No, it's not a better fit (it's off topic there) F) Because this site is for questions. Again, just because there are other places to get an answer (forums, wikipedia, books, tech support) doesn't mean a question isn't allowed here. – Tim
>
> @Tim Like it or not, it's up to you to explain how anything about 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi band shared across routers belongs in SE superuser. By contrast how could anything not apply to SE superuser? – Robbie Goodwin
>
> @RobbieGoodwin The only other place I can think of that this would be remotely on topic in would be Electrical Engineering but they do not seem to allow asking about consumer devices except for how to design or modify them so you'd really have to focus on the RF side, likely on a level advanced enough that an appropriate question would be impossible for a layperson who doesn't already know the answer to this question to compose, and the answer would probably be equally incomprehensible to a layperson. Just because you think the answer is obvious does not mean it is, nor not worth explaining – cat40
>
> @cat40 Fine and with respect, so what? Because it doesn't seem to fit anywhere else doesn't mean it must be accepted in SE superuser where it more clearly doesn't fit. Why is it hard for some to see that some Questions simply do not fit the spaces which have gone before, and need new spaces of their own to be created? –  Robbie Goodwin
>
> @RobbieGoodwin I should also note this question has already spawned two excellent answers, both of which are extremely accessible while still being technically correct. If that's not an argument for it being a good question I don't know what is. I will further note that you have no site reputation and if you feel it is not on topic just flag it for the moderators and shut up. You've made your arguments. – cat40
>
> @Cat40 Good for you and what does the fact that (two) people ignored the guidelines and chose to Answer a mis-placed Question mean? – Robbie Goodwin

So I feel the community is required to clear this up: is it on topic?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

From the [Help Centre](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) (emphasis mine)

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - **personal and home computer networking**